# mod_pagespeed rewrite all images into data:image format

Tags: image, apache, mod-pagespeed

I'm using [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod) and I'm searching for a way to rewrite all images into data:image format. Currently only small images are being included. I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ModPageSpeedImageInlineMaxBytes` option to configure the size threshold used by the `inline_images` filter. See the [image optimization documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-image-optimize) for more details.

However, you should consider carefully if you want to actually inline **all** images? While you'll save making another request for the inlined images, you'll also miss out on benefits such as cache extension, and pay a penalty if you reference an image multiple times on a page.